# Question on Gale-Stewart Theorem and Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, infinite-games

I am reading Kechris' descriptive set theory text book, and there is this Theorem regarding infinite games:

Gale-Stewart: Let $T$ be a non-empty pruned tree on $A$. Let $X\subset[T]$ be closed or open. Then $G(T,X)$ is determined.

There is this exercise: show that AC is equivalent to Gale-Stewart Theorem.

Assuming the exercise is true, if we consider the statement:

$\blacksquare$ Every infinite game is determined.

Then the statement $\blacksquare$ implies Gale-Stewart Theorem, which implies AC, which implies the negation of $\blacksquare$.

Does this mean ZF$+\blacksquare$ is inconsistent? Can we conclude that we can find a non-determined infinite game without using AC? If so, do you have any example in your mind?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $A$ in this context?

Comment: $A$ is a non-empty set. I meant to have $T\subset A^{<\mathbb{N}}$, a non-empty pruned tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct: $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves $\lnot \blacksquare$.

Note that $\blacksquare$ is not $\mathsf{AD}$, the Axiom of Determinacy. $\mathsf{AD}$ states that every Gale-Stewart game on $\omega^\omega$ is determined, which is much weaker than $\blacksquare$.

It is possible to prove in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone that there is a game on $\omega_1^\omega$ which is undetermined ($\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal). A reference is Theorem 10.2 in *Games with perfect information* by Mycielski, Chapter 3 in *Handbook of Game Theory with Economic Applications*, 1992, vol. 1, pp 41-70 ([link](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Eted/210F10/References/GameTheory/Chapter3copy.pdf)).

For a more explicit example of an undetermined game in $\mathsf{ZF}$, see the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/182541/2126) by Joel David Hamkins.