# Reverse mathematics and determinacy theorems

Tags: set-theory, game-theory, borel-sets, reverse-math

I recently learned about three determinacy theorems, and I am curious about the reverse mathematical-strength of (the countable analogs of) these theorems.

These theorems are [Zermelo's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%27s_theorem_(game_theory)) (Zermelo 1913), the Open Determinacy Theorem (Gale-Stewart 1953) and the [Borel Determinacy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_determinacy_theorem) (Martin 1974).

For reference, here are statements of each of these theorems. Let $A$ be any set, and let $G_A$ be any Gale-Stewart game on $A$. Endow $A$ with the discrete topology and $A^\omega$ with the product topology.

- Zermelo's Theorem states that, if $A$ is finite, then $G_A$ is determined.
- The Open Determinacy Theorem states that, if the payoff set for $G_A$ is an open or closed subset of $A^\omega$, then $G_A$ is determined.
- The Borel Determinacy Theorem states that, if the payoff set for $G_A$ is a Borel subset of $A^\omega$, then $G_A$ is determined.

I understand that the reverse mathematics of these theorems has been studied to some extent. In particular, the Open Determinacy Theorem is equivalent to AC under ZF ([Question on Gale-Stewart Theorem and Axiom of Choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555256/question-on-gale-stewart-theorem-and-axiom-of-choice)) and that the Borel Determinacy Theorem requires "repeated use" of the Axiom of Replacement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_determinacy_theorem) (Friedman 1971).

I am curious about where these theorems lie in the hierarchy of subsystems of second-order arithmetic, if we restrict these theorems to countable sets $A$. Does anyone know the answer to this question, or a source I could look to for more information?

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to start here: https://math.berkeley.edu/~antonio/papers/TDet21.pdf (The strength of Turing determinacy within second order arithmetic, A. Montalbán and R. A. Shore, Fund. Math.,  232  (2016), 249--268.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thanks! That answers a lot of what I was curious about.

Comment: In particular, that paper mentions the "classical" reverse mathematical fact that the Determinacy Theorem for "effectively open" (i.e., recursively enumerable or $\Sigma_1^0$) sets is equivalent to the system ATR${ }_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the earliest results in reverse mathematics was Steel's $1972$ proof that *each of* clopen and open determinacy is equivalent to $\mathsf{ATR}_0$. This should in my opinion be surprising, since $(i)$ every computable clopen game has a hyperarithmetic winning strategy but $(ii)$ there are computable open games without hyperarithmetic winning strategies. I'm aware of three proofs of this result, one via $\Sigma^1_1$-Separation (this is the proof presented in Simpson's book), one via Harrison orders/overspill (I don't recall where this is written up), and one via a "tree of strategies" (see the end of [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619399/why-does-the-cantor-bendixson-cupcake-theorem-need-transfinite-induction/3619707#3619707)).

As we climb up the determinacy hierarchy we rise rapidly in strength. $\mathsf{Z}_2$ cannot even prove $\Delta^0_4$ determinacy; the best it can do is prove that finite Boolean combinations of $\Sigma^0_3$ games are determined. This latter principle is schematic, and so itself constitutes a hierarchy; the relationship between the $n\Sigma^0_3$-determinacy hierarchy and the usual $\Pi^1_k$-comprehension hierarchy is subtle and was established by Montalban/Shore [1](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eantonio/papers/Delta4Det.pdf), [2](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eantonio/papers/DetPi3ConRev6.pdf).

We can go below $\mathsf{ATR}_0$ if we replace games on $\omega$ by games on $\{0,1\}$ (that is, move from games in Baire space to games in Cantor space); for example, clopen determinacy in Cantor space is equivalent to $\mathsf{WKL}_0$. See e.g. [Nemoto](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/malq.200610041).

Comment: I have a possibly stupid question: why do reverse mathematicians refer to determinacy for $\Sigma_1^0$ sets as “open determinacy”, when the $\Sigma_1^0$ sets are really just those that are *effectively* open? Is “open” simply shorthand for “effectively open”? Or does it have something to do with the fact that the $\Sigma_1^0$ sets are the sets that ATR${ }_0$ “knows” are open?

Comment: OR: Am I understanding Steel’s result wrong? Is it really about *all* open sets and not just the $\Sigma_1^0$ ones?

Comment: @GavinDooley I was being sloppy (although it's a common sloppiness): "$\Sigma^0_1$" should be "${\bf \Sigma^0_1}$", that is, all open sets.

Comment: No worries! Are all of the $\Sigma$'s, $\Pi$'s, and $\Delta$'s in your answer technically supposed to be the boldface versions?

Comment: @GavinDooley Yes, that's correct.